# Is the grid the new sidebar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, grid

With the new bootstrap thingy, is the left / right floated sidebar part of the past, since it can be reproduced with a grid layout now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do usually something like this:

```
   <div class ="row">     
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
         <article>...</article>
         <section class ="comments">...</section>
       </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <aside>...</aside>
      </div>
   </div>
```

There are also still semantic approaches like the [semantic grid](http://semantic.gs/). But I think that while `.row` and `.col` might semantically not be very expressive when it comes to their content, they are just very easy to use and if you used them once, you grasp their meaning very quick even without looking at the styles or the rendered page.

As styling regardless of structure is still not possible and probably never will be, I think that this might be a good middle ground. You have access to very easy to use grid-system like the one of bootstrap and you still have elements, which describe what 'semantic' meaning the content placed inside the grid is considered to have.

**To tackle your question directly**: From what I see everyday in the web-industry, 'non-semantic' grids (imho its just another kind of semantics, which you can mix easily if you have a set of clear rules, when to use what)  grew enormously popular, because they are the easiest way to tackle many if not most responsive layout-problems. Other approaches still exist. But as it stands for the standard layouts in the form of header nav, content, sidebar I think yes, grids have taken their place at least to a big extend and you see them less everyday.

Comment: "semantic grid" is pretty cool :D